# Invalid WKT polygon error

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver

We are trying to load the data in Solr through CSV file. The data is in the below format.

```
WKT(Its one column)
POLYGON ((44225.300000005 61616.3199999181 0.0, 43615.3000000049 61616.3199999181 0.0, 43615.3000000049 60606.3199999181 0.0, 44225.3000000049 60606.3199999181 0.0, 44225.300000005 61616.3199999181 0.0))
```

**Exception:**
ERROR: [doc=1255927] Error adding field 'wkt'='POLYGON ((44225.300000005 61616.3199999181 0.0, 43615.3000000049 61616.3199999181 0.0, 43615.3000000049 60606.3199999181 0.0, 44225.3000000049 60606.3199999181 0.0, 44225.300000005 61616.3199999181 0.0))' msg=Unable to parse shape given formats "lat,lon", "x y" or as WKT because org.locationtech.spatial4j.exception.InvalidShapeException: Latitude 1075.407656961003 is out of range: must range from -Math.PI/2 to Math.PI/2 input: POLYGON ((44225.300000005 61616.3199999181 0.0, 43615.3000000049 61616.3199999181 0.0, 43615.3000000049 60606.3199999181 0.0, 44225.3000000049 60606.3199999181 0.0, 44225.300000005 61616.3199999181 0.0))

**Note:** The above is valid polygon and its working find with Oracle Spatial database.

Comment: You have multiple issues here:  This is not valid WKT for `POLYGON` (it's `POLYGON Z` instead), and the coordinate system is not the expected decimal degrees (there is no 61616.32 degrees North)

Comment: So, do we need to convert this data from Polygon Z to polygon and load?
What do you mean by its not valid?. This data extracted from working oracle spatial table through SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(GEOM) WKT.

Comment: The error is complaining about the spatial reference, so the missing " Z" is not a showstopper.  Your data is NOT in degrees; this does appear to be a showstopper.

Comment: MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(3003, 262150, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(44225.300000005, 61616.3199999181, 0, 43615.3000000049, 61616.3199999181, 0, 43615.3000000049, 60606.3199999181, 0, 44225.3000000049, 60606.3199999181, 0, 44225.300000005, 61616.3199999181, 0)) 
This is exactly data from oracle spatial table. Yes, it's not in degrees but our data is not exactly geo coordinates.

Comment: Missing Z is not a problem for PostGIS either. It read POLYGON with three coordinates correctly as POLYGON Z. Test with `select st_astext(
st_geomfromtext('POLYGON ((44225.300000005 61616.3199999181 0.0, 43615.3000000049 61616.3199999181 0.0, 43615.3000000049 60606.3199999181 0.0, 44225.3000000049 60606.3199999181 0.0, 44225.300000005 61616.3199999181 0.0))'))`. For solving the real problem push the Oracle geometry through https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_cs-transform.htm#SPATL1075 and convert data into SRID=4326. That's the only projection that SOLR accepts.

Comment: @user30184 - I tried converting 
 Using: SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(geom,4326 ))
 After Conversion: POLYGON ((2533.92303770021 3530.35508512283 0.0, 2498.97261219722 3530.35508512283 0.0, 2498.97261219722 3472.48634781462 0.0, 2533.9230377002 3472.48634781462 0.0, 2533.92303770021 3530.35508512283 0.0))
Error: msg=Unable to parse shape given formats "lat,lon", "x y" or as WKT because org.locationtech.spatial4j.exception.InvalidShapeException: Latitude 61.61631999991807 is out of range:

Comment: @Cyril - Are you suggesting me to try positioning clockwise? Can you help me to know how to do that

Comment: you are sure of the correct coordinates, maybe you know what place on the ground this polygon falls?

Comment: These are not exactly coordinates on earth, it's coordinates of some Infra on the floor. These are coordinates of door, pillar, passage, Infra( some big structures) on floor. These plan prepared in AutoCAD and loaded into spatial.
Now, we are facing lot of performance issues hence we are looking for some alternative solutions.

Comment: You should have told that you use your local coordinate system. As far as I know SOLR supports only EPSG:4326 https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/spatial-search.html and then coordinates are between -90 - 90 latitude, 180 - 180 longitude. Values like 44224 and 61616 just are not acceptable. Perhaps you must convert your coordinates with your own formula to fit within the valid range.

Comment: @user30184 - Thanks. What is your suggestion on writing a formula is so easy to develop and maintain?. Are can we try this in some other solution like MongoDB ? Is MongoDB also have same limitation?
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/

Comment: Perhaps linear scaling https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.math/sj4tTuXpxE0. MongoDB is also bound to EPSG:4326 https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geometry/.

Comment: Seems, other than relational database (oracle spatial, postgis, etc) other nosql DB doesn't supports local coordinates.